# Can't clear string reference

Tags: c++, string, reference

I have the following program in which the private string mOutStr is filled with characters in method "FetchSessionStatus".

After that, if mOutStr is empty (aka: FetchSessionStatus doesn't fill it or some other error happened) mOutStr is replaced by a "default string" called mAliveMsg.

Finally mOutStr is passed *by reference* to method OnCommand. OnCommand writes the string inside a pipe and then should clear mOutStr. However, the clean never works: mOutStr remains filled.

```
void RtnodeSpvSession::EnqueueRead()
{
   std::string sCmd;
   FetchSessionStatus(); 
   (mOutStr.empty()) ? sCmd = mAliveMsg : sCmd = boost::ref(mOutStr);
   OnCommand(sCmd);
}

void RtnodeSpvSession::OnCommand(std::string& sCmd)
{
   std::cout << "Sending message " << sCmd.c_str() << " of "<< sCmd.size() << " size\n";
   write(fd[1], sCmd.c_str(), sCmd.size());
   sCmd.clear();
}

//Simplified version of FetchSessionStatus
void RtnodeSpvSession::FetchSessionStatus()
{
  mOutStr+="x";
}
```

The end result is that, cycle by cycle, mOutStr keeps increasing in size, which means sCmd.clear is not working (aka the pass by reference is not working) but I don't understand what I'm supposed to do.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you're right, I missed that tag.

Comment: What is the type of sCmd ? (could you provide the class definition for `RtnodeSpvSession`, or at least relevant information for your snippet that include definitions for sCmd ans mOutStr)

Comment: @Phantomas local variable in `RtnodeSpvSession::EnqueueRead()`: `std::string sCmd;`. I somehow have the feeling OP has some wrong expectations to what `boost::ref(mOutStr)` can achieve in `sCmd = boost::ref(mOutStr)`...

Comment: Oh right, missed that, thank for pointing it out.

Comment: `std::string sCmd;` is a local variable, and `OnCommand(sCmd);` will result in that this `sCmd` is cleared (just before it goes out of scope). As it is it appears a bit useless. Do you expected that `mOutStr` will somehow affected by this? It isn't.

Comment: How about this?: `std::string alive = mAliveMsg; FetchSessionStatus(); std::string &sCmd = mOutStr.empty() ? alive : mOutStr; OnCommand(sCmd);` Now, `sCmd` is a reference to a string which is conditionally initialized with either `alive` or `mOutStr`.

Comment: @Scheff I was hoping that assigning sCmd as a reference to mOutStr would in turn allow me to modify mOutStr by using sCmd itself

Comment: _I was hoping that assigning sCmd as a reference to mOutStr_ This is what I thought you expected. ;-) `sCmd` is not declared as reference. Hence, it cannot become a reference. Have you tried the suggested fix above?

Comment: @Scheff yes, although I had to do some minor changes since the actual code is slightly different from the simplified version I posted here, but it totally works

Answer (score 1):

Well the issue here is that you're not passing the string you think by reference.

In your case, boost::ref return a reference wrapper to `mOutStr`, however, when you assign it to `sCmd`, it'll copy the content of `mOutStr` into `sCmd`.

In your `OnCommand` function, `sCmd` is a reference to `sCmd` in `RtnodeSpvSession::EnqueueRead`, not to `mOutCmd`. If you want to clear `mOutCmd`, you have to either do it in `EnqueueRead`, or to actually pass it to the `OnCommand` function.

For clarification, `reference_wrapper<T>` offer an implicit conversion to `T&`, but `std::string::operator=(const &str)` does a copy of `str` into the left operand, and do not replace said operand.